# "Uninitalize" a jQuery action?

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I found this library at GitHub called [jTinder](https://github.com/do-web/jTinder), which basically allows me to setup cards that can be left swiped or right swiped. 
I setup the #tinderslide div: `<div id="tinderslide"><ul></ul></div>`

I set up the cards using a function:

```
function generate_cards(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_cards.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{"user":user_id},
        success:function(data){
            try{
                var parsedData=JSON.parse(data);
                for(var i=0;i<parsedData.length;i++){
                    var elem="<li class=\"card \"+parsedData[i].id>";
                    elem+="<div class=\"card_wrap\">";
                    elem+=<img src=\""+parsedData[i].picture.url+"\">";
                    elem+="<div class=\"name_location_wrapper\">";
                    elem+="<span class=\"name\">"+parsedData[i].first_name+" "+parsedData[i].last_name+"</span>";
                    elem+="<span class=\"location\"></span>";
                    elem+="</div></div></li>";
                    $("#tinderslide ul").prepend(elem);
                }
                dfd.resolve();
            }
            catch(er){
                console.log(er);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

and called the jTinder action:

```
function init(){
        $("#tinderslide").jTinder({
            onDislike: function (item) {
                $(".last").remove();
                $(".card").last().addClass("last");
            },
            onLike: function (item) {
                $(".last").remove();
                $(".card").last().addClass("last");
            },
            animationRevertSpeed: 100,
            animationSpeed: 100,
            threshold: 2
        });
    }
```

I have `d3d` set up as a `$.Deferred` variable and once it's resolved, I call the `init()` function.

I add ".last" to the last card for changing the background according to what the current object is, since the cards are arranged in reverse order, i.e. the last element is the first.

I then add the first batch of cards from a PHP file, which works fine. I can add the first 10 cards and store the responses just fine.

Next, I checked if the number of cards in the stack is less than 5, in which case, I fetch the next 10 cards. **Here lies the problem.**

Since the #tinderslide div is already initialized with the jTinder method, I can't initialize it again. The closest I've come to a solution is to check whether the card stack is empty, use `$("#tinderslide").remove()` to remove the #tinderslide div entirely, and then add it again, append the next cards and reinitialized, which seems to be working for now.

However, my question is: is there a more efficient way to do this, without having to delete and recreate the div entirely?

Comment: "I can't initialize it again" Why would you want to?

Comment: Because once I add cards, the swipe doesn't work until I remove the #tinderslide and add it back again. I&#39;m assuming it&#39;s because the li elements that I add later aren't initialized as part of the jTinder action.

Comment: So you want a workaround for what "doesn't work" rather than finding out why it doesn't work and if it's possible to fix it?

Comment: Is it possible to fix, though? That'd help a lot, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the library

Comment: Widget plugins should really include a `destroy` method but this one doesn't. Your `#tinderslide` replacement hack is probably the best option available to you.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 So I could possibly write a destroy method for the library then. I'll try that and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just make sure everything that is done during initialization is undone by your destroy method.

Comment: There's only three bind statements in the initialization, so I'm going to try and see if unbinding those three work. Will post just as soon as I try it out.

Comment: Alternatively, write a `.add()` method, then you can just loop through the next set of 10 cards and `.add()`, `.add()`, `.add()` ...

Comment: Use of jQuery's `.bind()` indicates that `jTinder` is pretty out of date. You might take the opportunity to change `.bind()` to `.on()`. To undo either of those, you can use `.off()`.

Comment: It worked, just want to confirm if `$("#tinderslide").data('plugin_jTinder').destroy();` is safe to call?

Comment: Yeah, it's safe enough, but cumbersome. As you have discovered, the plugin isn't set up to be extended with fresh methods so the only clean way to add `.destroy()` is to patch the source - add `destroy: function() {...}` to `Plugin.prototype`. And be sure to include a big comment to remind you it's a patch.

Comment: Then you would call `$("#tinderslide").jTinder("destroy");`.

Answer (score 1):

I added a destroy function to the `Plugin.prototype`:

```
destroy: function(element){
    $(element).unbind();
    $(this.element).removeData();
}
```

and then called `$("#tinderslide").data('plugin_jTinder').destroy();`, which seems to work. Thanks to [Roamer-1888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3478010/roamer-1888) for the inputs!